# I have a problem with accessing "comments" table in databases with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a code that have an access to my database's "comments" table. I did a connection variable and created all the stuff in order to get table. But I when save and refresh the page, it is showing this error below. What's the problem?

```
  <?php
    // connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect(
    $config['db']['server'],
    $config['db']['username'],
    $config['db']['password'],
    $config['db']['name']
);

if ($connection == false)
{
    echo 'Error!<br>';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
// comments
        $сomments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `articles_id` DESC LIMIT 5");
        while ($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)) 
        {
          ?>
          <article class="article">
            <div class="article__image" style="background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo md5($com['email']); ?>?s=125);"></div>
            <div class="article__info">
              <a href="/article.php?id=<?php echo $com['articles_id']; ?>"><?php echo $com['author']; ?></a>

              <div class="article__info__preview"><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($com['text']), 0, 100, 'utf-8') .  ' ...'; ?></div>
            </div>
          </article>
          <?php
        }
      ?>
```

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in W:\domains\itblog.kg\includes\sidebar.php on line 56 . What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the query (`$comments = mysqli_query(...`) is returning a null value. This means that there has been some problem with the query.

Try changing the code like this:

```
 $сomments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `articles_id` DESC LIMIT 5");

// start new
        if (!$comments) {
               echo "Error - " . mysqli_error($connection);
        } else 
// end new

        while ($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)) 
        {
          ?>
          <article class="article">
...
```

(Note that you should also surround the whole while loop with braces `{}`, as it is the `else` clause, to avoid future errors. But it should work like that.)

The script should report the error it is seeing and it should allow you to fix the query.

Edit - I'd bet that the `comments` table does not have an `articles_id` column - probably it should be `article_id`.

Comment: -Thanks. I tried. But it's again showing me the same error: `Error - Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in W:\domains\itblog.kg\includes\sidebar.php on line 59`

Comment: That's really weird. So `$comments` is null but there's no error in the `$connection` mysqli handle. Could you try adding `echo mysqli_connect_error();` right after the `mysqli_connect`? In theory that should be caught by the `if ($connection == false)` just below, but that's about the only explanation I can come up with... [Edit - and make sure that the lines are inserted between the `mysqli_query` and the `while`]

Comment: I did as you said. But, the result is the same :(

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that something else is wrong in the sidebar.php script. Would it be possible for you to show the full code?